# MySQL: get items by group

Tags: mysql

I have table like this:

```
_______________________________________________
| item_id  | group_id | item_name  | quantity |
-----------------------------------------------
|        1 | 0001     |   cup_1    |        5 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        2 | 0001     |   cup_2    |        3 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        3 | 0002     |   spoon_1  |        2 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        4 | 0002     |   spoon_2  |        2 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        5 | 0003     |   table_1  |        6 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        6 | 0004     |   table_2  |        7 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        7 | 0004     |   table_3  |        1 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        8 | 0005     |   chair_1  |        5 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        9 | 0005     |   chair_2  |        4 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I need to show to the user 20 items from this table, but items with the same group_id should be grouped in one.
So cup_1 and cup_2 are like one item.
The problem is that there could be any number of items in group.
So in fact I need to show 20 groups of items.

I tried to use "group by" statement, but it did not work in this case

How could I compose such query?

Thanks!

UPD.
I'm trying to get items in first 'n' groups (or next 'n' groups - it's for catalog).
The result should look like previous table.
For example:

`SELECT * FROM my_table ... LIMIT 1,2`:

```
_______________________________________________
| item_id  | group_id | item_name  | quantity |
-----------------------------------------------
|        3 | 0002     |   spoon_1  |        2 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        4 | 0002     |   spoon_2  |        2 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        5 | 0003     |   table_1  |        6 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

First 2 groups only

`SELECT * FROM my_table ... LIMIT 3,2` - next 2 groups and so on:

```
_______________________________________________
| item_id  | group_id | item_name  | quantity |
-----------------------------------------------
|        6 | 0004     |   table_2  |        7 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        7 | 0004     |   table_3  |        1 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        8 | 0005     |   chair_1  |        5 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        9 | 0005     |   chair_2  |        4 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Engine: MyISAM

Comment: can you provide an example of the output you expect?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch done

Comment: Your output is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [`Coalesce` function](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php):

```
SELECT 
    Coalesce(item_id,0) as item_id, 
    group_id, 
    Coalesce(item_name,0) as item_name, 
    Coalesce(quantity,0) as quantity
FROM my_table
GROUP by group_id
```

BTW, in MySQL this would work too:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
GROUP by group_id
```

Comment: It's not realy what i need. It gives me list like 1 ...11-11 ...cup_1 ... 5 next 3 .... 22-11 ... spoon_1 .. 2. But i need all items in first 'n' groups. I updated my post with output